# Convert multiple rows to columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to convert rows to columns in pandas, my sample data frame looks like

```
Scode   Pname   Town    State     Cycle    Sqty     Fqty
6000    Naro    Hyd       TS      Feb/Mar   10     20
6000    Naro    Vij       TS      Apr/May   10     20
6000    Naro    Blore     KR      Feb/Mar   100    200
6000    Naro    Cochin    KR      Apr/May   100    200
```

I thought it would work with unstack multiple index

```
df = df.set_index(['State', 'C&F', 'HQ','Sample Code','PName','Cycle']).unstack().T
```

My sample output

```
                        TS    TS        KR       KR
                        Hyd   Vij       Blore    Cochin
Scode   Pname   Cycle   Sqty  Fqty      Sqty    Fqty
6000    Naro    Feb/Mar 10     10        100        100
6000    Naro    Apr/May 20     20        200         200
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need create MultiIndex by all columns which are not  identifier variables like `Sqty` and `Fqty` columns, then create `MultiIndex Series` by `stack` and last reshape by `unstack`:

```
df = (df.set_index(['Scode', 'Pname', 'Cycle','State','Town'])
        .rename_axis('new', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .unstack(['State','Town','new']))
print (df)
State                  TS                       KR                     
Town                  Hyd         Vij        Blore        Cochin       
new                  Sqty  Fqty  Sqty  Fqty   Sqty   Fqty   Sqty   Fqty
Scode Pname Cycle                                                      
6000  Naro  Apr/May   NaN   NaN  10.0  20.0    NaN    NaN  100.0  200.0
            Feb/Mar  10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN  100.0  200.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: close enough but not actual desired output

Comment: @jezrael not sure how you got the output. but all columns are getting unstacked.. my data frame is like 60*11 size !!!

Comment: @nick - Can you add your R code to sample data for same output like in your question?

Answer (score 0):

for converting rows into columns you can simply use pivot_table.you can also change values according to requirment

```
         ` import pandas as pd
            pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Scode','Pname','Cycle','State','Town'],values= 
            ["Town","Sqty","Fqty"], columns=[ "State"])
```